# Multiple line batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch. So I was playing with commands and I found that I dont undarstand how to write multiple lines of commands in batch here is example.

```
start cmd.exe /k "ipconfig && whoami && getmac  && netplwiz " 

%windir%\system32\wuapp.exe
```

This will work fine but I was thinking how to make it easier for reading and make it with comments and I cant figure out how to do it. Here is what I tried.

```
start cmd.exe ^
/k "ipconfig ^
&& whoami ^ 
&& getmac ^ 
&& netplwiz "

%windir%\system32\wuapp.exe
```

So this does not work I know this symbol ^ is continuation of line. It does work for ipconfig to showup in cmd but rest commands are ignored.

Here is example with multiple lines and it works fine

```
set wind=%windir%
set winsys=%windir%\system32

REM Checks if any browsers are currently running. If so, they will be terminated.
start /min /wait wscript.exe %~dp0CheckforProcesses.vbs

REM Uninstalling Java JRE 6 Update 29
start /wait msiexec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83216029FF} /quiet

REM Uninstalling Java JRE 7 Update 55
start /wait msiexec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83217055FF} /quiet

REM Uninstalling Java JRE 7 Update 65
start /wait msiexec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217065FF} /quiet

REM Installing Java JRE 7 Update 65
msiexec /i "%~dp0JRE\765\jre7_65.msi" /norestart /qn
```

I hope my question is clear and I am sorry if not. I know this commands in my example not useful in that contest , but this is not the point. The point I want to use multiple lines for better reading batch file code and not have 300 characters in one line (I hope it makes sense).
In my head I have only one explanation that some commands is have to be written in one line and there is no other way around.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the & Symbol.

See here: http://commandwindows.com/command1.htm

For example:

```
@echo off
ipconfig
whoami
getmac
netplwiz
echo\
echo Press the Space bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Edit: I believe a line break may also work.
Edit 2: added example.

Comment: thank you for fast respond so I edit it and I run to another problem 

        @echo off
 
        ipconfig &
        whoami &
        getmac &
        netplwiz  

        %windir%\system32\wuapp.exe `

the windows update gui will only show up when I close cmd gui. is any way i can fix that?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, batch files are automatically interpreted by cmd.exe.  That means you can just use new lines and your program will run fine.  The problem with this is that the console closes as soon as they finish. To fix this, just add the line `pause > nul` and you can click space to close.

Comment: yeah line break and & symbol works great the only problem is gui update window showing up only after I close gui netplwiz, well may be i wil figure out how to fix it thank you

Comment: Hm if i put to execute  %windir%\system32\wuapp.exe win update first it is working fine I am wondering why

Comment: You can run multiple commands in parallel using the `start` command. See here : http://ss64.com/nt/start.html